# How to re-start a service if user stops the main process?

Tags: android-intent

I'm developing an application for Android devices, these devices owned by an enterprise are the working tool of their workers. The application has two services which need to be running 24/7, now the services are running fine, starting automatically when at device boot, etc.. but there are some "advanced users" who have learned to stop the main process from the applications manager (settings) then the two services are killed.

The application has an activity which requires a password to manage some parameters and for stopping a running the services.

My question is like this:

[How can I restart my app service if user stops (kills) it from settings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7162704/how-can-i-restart-my-app-service-if-user-stops-kills-it-from-settings)

Is there any way to re-start the services? maybe:

- with a BrodcastReceiver (Screen_On, Screen_off): but if the main process is killed, the BrodcastReceiver is killed too, isn't it?
- Another service checking the other services: but it can be killed too, isn't it?

Thanks for your help!!!